# Use fields from data() as chart data - FusionCharts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

I want to show simple charts using Vue 2 and FusionCharts. I'm fetching my data from firebase and I run some calculations before I can fetch this to FusionCharts component. As these calculations are performed the result is stored in values in Vue's data function. I was following [this](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/vue/your-first-chart-using-vuejs) link here. Problem is it defines chartData outside the export default. My question is how do i use values in my data function to populate my chart? My code looks something like this:

```
export default {
  name: "dash",
  data: () => ({
    users: [],
    total: 0,
    activeCount: 0,
    maleCount: 0,
    femaleCount: 0,
    newUssrs: 0
  }),
  computed: {
    chartData: [
      {
        label: "Male",
        value: this.maleCount
      },
      {
        label: "Female",
        value: this.femaleCount
      }
    ],
    dataSrc: {
      chart: {
        caption: "Total User Count",
        subcaption: "",
        xaxisname: "Gender",
        yaxisname: "User counts",
        numbersuffix: "",
        theme: "fusion"
      },
      data: this.chartData
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

computed properties need to be functions which return the computed data. Like:

```
computed: {
    chartData() {
        return [
          {
            label: "Male",
            value: this.maleCount
          },
          {
            label: "Female",
            value: this.femaleCount
          }
        ]
    },
    dataSrc() {
        return {
          chart: {
            caption: "Total User Count",
            subcaption: "",
            xaxisname: "Gender",
            yaxisname: "User counts",
            numbersuffix: "",
            theme: "fusion"
          },
          data: this.chartData
        }
    }
},
```